# Binary Formatter, Set Position to Deserialize Particular Object

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, deserialization, filestream

I want to ask about serialize/deserialize object with binary formatter. well i'm trying to deserialize object in FileStream that contain many objects that has been serialized one by one. The size of an object is too big to be saved in process memmory that's why i don't pack all of objects in one such as: **List** because they are too big in process memory So i serialize as much as needed in many times. with this way  it won't take many process memmory because i just process one object alternately not all of objects. take a look at sketch that i mean

```
<FileStream>
----Object 1-----Size = 100 Mb------index = 0
----Object 2-----Size = 100 Mb------index = 1
----Object 3-----Size = 100 Mb------index = 2
----Object 4-----Size = 100 Mb------index = 3
----Object 5-----Size = 100 Mb------index = 4
----Object 6-----Size = 100 Mb------index = 5
</FileStream>
```

Serialization object is also successfully now i got a problem  to deserialized an object.
here is the problem:
in **List** we can take an item with index. so if we like to take fifth index we can call it such as:

```
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    list(0) = "object1";
    list(1) = "object2";
    list(2) = "object3";
    list(3) = "object4";
    list(4) = "object5";
    list(5) = "object6";
    object fifthIndex = list[5]; // here we can get item based index
```

Well now the problem is how can i get objects with fifth index just like ***List Method*** on six Deserialization object in a filestream with Binary Formatter. i know in FileStream there is a property that named "FileStream.Position" but it does not like Index, it looks like a random number when i have deserialize/serialize an object. maybe it will increase random number.

actually i have succeeded with this but i bet this is not best way take a look at my code that i have ever tried:

```
object GetObjectStream(FileStream fs, int index)
{
    if (fs != null)
    {
        BinaryFormatter binaryformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        bool isFinished = false; int count = 0;
        while (isFinished == false)
        {
            try
            {
                object objectdeserialized = binaryformatter.Deserialize(fs);
                if (count == index) return objectdeserialized;
                count++;
            }
            catch
            {
                isFinished = true;
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

these codes will ***"foreach***" every object that has been serialized and then deserialize every objects. i bet my codes are not the best way because to Deserialize object that contain 100 MB maybe it will take long time, I don't even know the object except index that ever be deserialized will be disposed or not? i want method just like a **"Serialization Leap."**

your answer is very helpfull and usefull for me if we can solve this problem.

Thanks before..

Comment: Show the code that is serializing the List.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov serializing List object that i mean is : 
binaryformatter.Serialize(new List<object>());

Let's just say there are a lot of items in new List<object>() then i serialize it.

Comment: But if you have lots of items in the list how they fit in memory? I thought that was your problem in the first place - running out of memory because the list is too huge.

Comment: List<Object>, It was just the parable to be understand i don't write the objects in List at all but i serialize one by one and disposing the object after saved in File in many times.
the parable, how can i pick the item just like List<T> i mean by index. but this is a deserialization stream

Comment: So you are appending to the existing file?

Comment: yes, It may be called appending the content of the file by serialization object in one file.

Answer (score 1):

Each object will most likely take a different amount of space to serialize - data packs differently, especially for things like strings and arrays. Basically, to do this *efficiently* (i.e. without reading every object in full each time), you would want to either:

- prefix each object with the amount of data it takes, by serializing it to a `MemoryStream`, storing the `.Length` (any way that is convenient to you; a 4 byte little-endian chunk would suffice), and then copy the data you wrote to `MemoryStream` to the output; then you can skip to the n'th item by n-times-(read 4 bytes as an int, skipping that many bytes)
- in a separate index, store the `.Position` of the base stream just before you serialize each object; then to read the nth object, you use the index to find the position you need, and scroll to there

Actually, you were quite lucky here: `BinaryFormatter` isn't actually documented as being safe to append, but as it happens it *does* kinda work out ok it you do that - but this isn't true for all serialization formats.

Personally, though, I'd question whether there is simply a different design that could be used here.

Comment: Ok i got it. with your second solution, now the problem is, we got all **index/position length** after we serializing all object that i have. well, now how can i put the **"Index/Position"** to the header of File while we have done serializing until 6 times. how can i set the position to 0 to serializing the header while the Serialization Stream is getting Error because the position is untidy.

Comment: @Rizky you can't magically move things to the "header" of the file after-the-fact; first, that needs you to move ***all the rest of the data***, and second: that *changes the offsets* - although for that, you could probably simply cheat by offsetting everything by the size of the header. But at that point you have made things fundamentally non-appendable, hence why I used the word "separate", which would allow you to keep using it the way you are. If you want a single file, **and** you want it to be appendable, you'd need to use the first approach, or a different serializer./

Comment: i have followed your advice, it was work out..! i read back your advice that this is using **MemoryStream**  then copy the content of data and index position also, this is work fine! I very thankful to you but this still not solve my other problem. now back at my question: i need to serialize data with the amount up to 100 MB per object. with this size, even if i need to serialize 20 object, i need to process it all at once in memorystream, the size will be reach 2 GB in Process Memory! this will causing a **Program Crashing,** of course this problem is quite difficult.

Comment: actually Appendable output or not it doesn't matter to me i just need to put my resources in one file then load it back for certain Objects (according to state of the Program) at runtime. Hence why i need to deserialize object by index.

Answer (score 0):

```
----Write objects to file---
1. Keep a Dictionary<KeyType, long> dict.  KeyType probably int if you key on an object number. 
2. open file FileX for output; FileX.position = 0 at this point.
3. For each object: 
         update dictionary(oject.key, fileX.Position)
         Serialize object to FileX (note: FileX.Position is updated by BinaryFormatter)
4. Close FileX. Save Dictionary (serialize to another file).

----Read Back Object---
Use Dictionary to get offset based on key of object you want:
     do FileX.Seek(offset, 0); formatter.deserialize(FileX) to get back the
object you wish.
```